# Different retry strategies for different consumers in Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-retry

We are dealing with a scenario where we need different retry strategies for different consumers in same application.

Please refer to below figure (a brief architecture diagram):

[image]

The `main_consumer` consumes payload from `main_topic` and tries to send it to an API. If the API processing fails, we are writing this failed payload into another topic called `error_topic`. There is a different consumer `(error_consumer)` which consumes from `error_topic` and sends the payload to API again with 3 retry attempts. If it is still a failure, then `error_consumer` pushes this payload into `DLQ`.

***Problem we are facing:***

We need `main_consumer` not to retry on failure and `error_consumer` to retry 3 times on failure. We took `maxAttempts` as 1 for `main_consumer` and `maxAttempts` as 3 for `error_consumer`. But with this configuration, `main_consumer` is retrying 3 times and `error_consumer` once. It is working quite opposite to what we expected.

P.S : We tried interchanging the `maxAttempts` for both consumers(which is illogical) in vain.

*Below is the Spring cloud stream application configuration we are using:*

We are running the application with both the below profiles.

***application-main.yml***

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          main-consumer-channel:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
      bindings:
        main-consumer-channel:
          destination: main_topic
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 1
            backOffInitialInterval: 5000
            backOffMultiplier: 2
```

***application-error-retry.yml***

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          error-consumer-channel:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
      bindings:
        error-consumer-channel:
          destination: error_topic
          consumer:
             maxAttempts: 3
             backOffInitialInterval: 5000
             backOffMultiplier: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Inputs.class)
public class So57522645Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57522645Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener("input1")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        System.out.println("main: " + in);
        throw new RuntimeException("fail");
    }

    @StreamListener("input2")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println("error: " + in);
        throw new RuntimeException("fail");
    }

    @StreamListener("input3")
    public void listen3(String in) {
        System.out.println("final: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> template.send("main", "test".getBytes());
    }

}

interface Inputs {

    @Input
    MessageChannel input1();

    @Input
    MessageChannel input2();

    @Input
    MessageChannel input3();

}
```

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input1:
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 1
          destination: main
          group: grp1
        input2:
          consumer:
            max-attempts: 3
          destination: error.main.grp1
          group: grp2
        input3:
          destination: error.error.main.grp1.grp2
          group: grp3
      kafka:
        bindings:
          input1:
            consumer:
              enable-dlq: true
          input2:
            consumer:
              enable-dlq: true
```

and

```
main: test
error: test
error: test
error: test
final: test
```

Answer (score 1):

Per spring documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/_configuration_options.html, maxAttempts configuration should be under

> "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.consumer."

In your configuration, it looks like is under

> "spring.cloud.stream.**kafka**.bindings.<channelName>.consumer."

MaxAttempts doesn't seem to be a valid configuration for kafka binding props - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Comment: That is correct; `maxAttempts` is common across all binders.

Comment: @Nitin Thanks for pointing that out. That was mistake I made while forming the question to be asked in here. I have updated the question with my original configuration now.

Comment: @GaryRussell I didn't understand what you said. Does it mean we can't have multiple retry `maxAttempts` for multiple binders ?  If No, is there any other approach that we can try ? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: No; that's not what I meant at all. There are common binding properties that apply to  all binders (e.g. `maxAttempts`) and binder-specific binding properties. Each binding can have different property values. See my answer; your scenario works just fine for me.